# Vala, string to enum

Tags: string, enums, vala

Is there a way to convert a string to an enum in vala:

```
string foo = "Enum1";
MY_ENUM theEnum = MY_ENUM.get_value_by_name(foo);
```

```
enum MY_ENUM {
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3
}
```

So in this example "theEnum" would have the value: MY_ENUM.Enum1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the runtime type system provided by GLib's GObject library. There are [`EnumClass`](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.EnumClass.html) and [`EnumValue`](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.EnumValue.html). These provide introspection at runtime and allow an enum to be initialised from a string.

The syntax is a bit complex at present, although it may be possible for someone to modify the Vala compiler to make it easier, but that is a significant piece of work.

An example:

```vala
void main () {
    try {
        MyEnum? the_enum_value;
        the_enum_value = MyEnum.parse ("FIRST");
        print (@"$(the_enum_value)\n");
    } catch (EnumError error) {
        print (@"$(error.message)\n");
    }
}

errordomain EnumError {
    UNKNOWN_VALUE
}

enum MyEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD;

    public static MyEnum parse (string value) throws EnumError {
        EnumValue? a;
        a = ((EnumClass)typeof (MyEnum).class_ref ()).get_value_by_name ("MY_ENUM_" + value);
        if (a == null) {
            throw new EnumError.UNKNOWN_VALUE (@"String $(value) is not a valid value for $(typeof(MyEnum).name())");
        }
        return (MyEnum)a.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better off using nicks here

Comment: A nick name would help if a more human readable name was required when printing the value, not sure it helps much going from a nick name string to the value though? There's some code https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/commit/ba1258de7cc9e1dcd5c8068f04da245c13c0e6b2 and discussion https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/issues/976

Comment: I could've used a switch statement in a function attached to the enum but that seemed like not the best idea but I might just use a switch statement after all because this solution seems a bit messy as well.

Comment: nicks are used when persisting with GSettings and as GAction targets